# Split-step FFT: Evolving a wave freely makes it spread

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, fourier-transform

Is there a "quantum" meaning in the wave spreading away while evolving it in time?

For instance, we use a wave like:

$\Psi(x,0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2 \pi {\Delta x}^ 2}} \exp \left( i k_0 x - \frac{(x-x_0)^ 2}{4 {\Delta x}^ 2} \right)$

where $k_0$ as I understand is a proxy for the wave energy (for a free particle):

$E_0 = \frac{k_0^2 \hbar^2}{2m}$

Then we use split-step and FFT for propagating it in time:

$\Psi(x,t+\Delta t) \approx \exp(-\frac{i \hat{V}(x) \Delta t}{2 \hbar}) \exp(-\frac{i \hat{K} \Delta t}{\hbar}) \exp(-\frac{i \hat{V}(x) \Delta t}{2 \hbar}) \Psi(x,t)$

We approach this as follows:

1. $\eta(x) = \exp(-\frac{i \hat{V}(x) \Delta t}{2 \hbar}) \Psi(x,t)$
2. $\xi(k) = \exp(-\frac{i (2 \pi k)^ 2 \hbar \Delta t}{2m}) \mathscr{F} (\eta(x)) $
3. $\Psi(x,t+\Delta t) \approx \exp(-\frac{i \hat{V}(x) \Delta t}{2 \hbar}) \mathscr{F}^{-1} (\xi(k))$

The steps 1-3 are repeated many times for small time steps, usually $\Delta t \approx 1\times 10^{-18} s$

What we observe is that the wave spreads away like:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am sorry for the bad images, I hope it is possible to understand them.

But, the thing is, even for waves propagating without potentials, or waves with very high energies, they always behave like this.

Also, when we try to simulate solid state devices, we use the effective mass approximation, and it makes the wave persist for a little longer.

Sure, it is possible that I am making something wrong.

Comment: I support Cosmos's answer and I can attest that this is exactly the kind of behavior one sees in the SSFFT. If you're unsure, you can hammer together a version of SSFFT in a few lines in Mathematica  or the like. This might give you confidence that all is OK. But, if your FFT is working, the likelihood of coding mistake is low: remember, operator splitting is a very simple, neat algorithm. I'm not altogether sure about the $2\pi$ factor in step 2; I make it to be $\exp\left(-\frac{i \,k^ 2 \,\hbar \Delta t}{2m}\right)$.

Comment: Check this, but a mistake along these lines will simply alter your energy scale, not the fundamental behavior (i.e. like changing units for $V$).

Comment: Rod Vance, thanks for your comment. I was really not confident about the results, it is very good to know that it is something normal and has some meaning also. Well, about the $2 \pi$ that's one thing I got in a mathematics book, never checked for being honest, but I will, thanks again. The ssfft, thanks for mentioning, I'll give it a try, seems to be a way more fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [free wave packet solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet#Dispersive) of the dispersive 
Schrödinger equation almost always (*) spread like this, independently of your group velocity $k_0$ of the wavepacket. If you set that to 0, they'd still spread like this, in place.  It is the heart of quantum mechanics.

The intuitive reason is that the initial width *a* spreads to 
$$ \sqrt{a^2 + (\hbar t/m)^2 \over a}~,$$
so, eventually (very quickly, in practice) it
grows linearly in time, as   $\hbar t/(m\sqrt{a})$. Why?

This linear growth is a reflection of the (time-invariant) momentum uncertainty: the wave packet is confined at first to a narrow region $Δx\sim \sqrt{a/2}$, and so has a momentum which is uncertain (according to the  [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) ) by the amount  $\Delta p\sim\hbar/\sqrt{2a}$; thus, a spread in velocity of  $\hbar /m\sqrt{2a}$; and thus in the subsequent position by $\Delta x \sim \hbar t/m\sqrt{2a}$.

The [uncertainty relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) is then a strict inequality, very far from saturation. The initial uncertainty  *ΔxΔp=ħ/2*  has now increased by a factor of  *ħt/ma*  for large  *t*. This is seen as a generic property of Fourier analysis, then.

---

- (*) *Almost always*: sometimes (rarely) the introduction of interaction terms in dispersive equations, such as for the quantum harmonic oscillator potential, may result in the emergence of envelope-non-dispersive, classical-looking solutions ([coherent states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states#The_wavefunction_of_a_coherent_state)). They don't spread, sort of like classical objects! Such "minimum uncertainty states" do saturate the uncertainty principle, permanently. Also see the peculiar [Airy wave-train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet#The_Airy_wave_train).

Comment: Cosmas, thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it. About this terms that we could introduce in the wave shape, that would cause it to become like a coherent state. Would you point me in any direction for finding how to do that? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also, thanks for the references, I am enjoying them.